# Set 802.1x EAPas security param in WifiConfig instance

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

I was developing an app where I need to get access to the WiFi which the device is connected, in order to set some configuration.

My main problem is although I identify almost where to recover almost all the parameters, I turn in to a trouble when I try to set the security into "802.1x EAP".

Here it's what I tried:

MainActivity.kt

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun processWifiConfiguration(context: Context) {
        /**
         * Set the following wifi params:
         * Seguridad: 802.1x EAP
         * Método EAP: EAP PEAP
         * Autenticación fase 2: MSCHAPv2
         * Certificado CA: Sin certificado
         * Identidad: ***********
         * Identidad anónima: Nada
         * Contraseña: ******
         *
         */
        val wifiConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
        wifiConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
        wifiConfig.phase2Method = Phase2.MSCHAPV2
        wifiConfig.caCertificate = null
        wifiConfig.anonymousIdentity = null


        val info = WifiInfo(
            security = WifiConfiguration.SECURITY_TYPE_EAP,
            eapMethod = wifiConfig.eapMethod,
            phase2Auth = wifiConfig.phase2Method,
            caCertificate = wifiConfig.caCertificate,
            anonymousIdentity = wifiConfig.anonymousIdentity,
            //TODO: Check where cames from the identity and password param.
            identity = wifiConfig.identity,
            password = wifiConfig.password
        )
        viewModel.launchWifiConfiguration(context = context, info = info)
    }
```

SharedViewModel.kt

```
private val wifi: WifiManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager


fun launchWifiConfiguration(context:Context, info: WifiInfo){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _isLoading.emit(true)
            if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled){
                wifi.isWifiEnabled = true
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                wifi.callerConfiguredNetworks.map {
                    it.enterpriseConfig.identity = info.identity
                    it.enterpriseConfig.password = info.password
                    it.enterpriseConfig.eapMethod = info.eapMethod
                    it.enterpriseConfig.caCertificate = info.caCertificate
                    it.enterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = info.anonymousIdentity
                    it.enterpriseConfig.phase2Method = info.phase2Auth
                    it.setSecurityParams(info.security)
                    Log.d("es.paytef", "Settea los params del wifi en S")
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
                }
            }else{
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return@launch
                }
                wifi.configuredNetworks.map {
                    it.enterpriseConfig.identity = info.identity
                    it.enterpriseConfig.password = info.password
                    it.enterpriseConfig.eapMethod = info.eapMethod
                    it.enterpriseConfig.caCertificate = info.caCertificate
                    it.enterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = info.anonymousIdentity
                    it.enterpriseConfig.phase2Method = info.phase2Auth
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        it.setSecurityParams(info.security)
                    }
                    Log.d("es.paytef", "Settea los params del wifi")
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The WifiInfo class is a data class which I create to keep the data.